# equivalent characterizations of manifolds such that configuration spaces are homotopy equivalent

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homotopy-theory, geometric-topology

Let $M$ and $N$ be manifolds. If $M$ is homeomorphic to $N$, then the $k$-th configuration spaces $F(M,k)$ is homeomorphic to $F(N,k)$. If $M$ is homotopy equivalent to $N$, then the $k$-th configuration spaces $F(M,k)$ is not necessarily homotopy equivalent  to $F(N,k)$.

In https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Isotopy_(in_topology), the notion "isotopy" is defined (different from the "isotopy" in geometry of submanifolds):

An isotopy is a fibrewise-continuous mapping $f:M\times[0,1]\to N\times[0,1]$ such that $f$ takes the fibre $M\times t$ homeomorphically onto a subset of the fibre $N\times t$.

**Question:** If $M$ is isotopic to $N$, will $F(M,k)$ be homotopy equivalent to $F(N,k)$? I want to find equivalent conditions when $F(M,k)$ will be homotopy equivalent to $F(N,k)$. Is it possible?

Comment: Isotopy is a notion that only makes sense in an ambient space. If two maps are isotopic, their images are automatically homeomorphic.

Comment: It's an outstanding conjecture that lens spaces $L(p,q), L(p',q')$ have homotopy equivalent double configuration spaces if and only if they're homeomorphic. Maybe test your equivalent condition on this case first.

Comment: Your definition of "$M$ being isotopic to $N$" is equivalent to $M$ being embedded in $N$. I seriously doubt that will say anything too drastic about the configuration spaces. In the link you gave $N$ is the ambient manifold, and they are certainly not saying "$M$ is isotopic to $N$".